# Application of squeeze theorem

Tags: limits, analysis

I don't really know how the Squeeze theorem works and I tried applying it to solve this limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\text{ } \frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\dots+\frac{1}{(n+n)^2}$$
So
$$\frac{n}{(n+n)^2}\leq \frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\dots+\frac{1}{(n+n)^2} \leq \frac{n}{n^2} $$
Then:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\text{ } \frac{n}{n^2}=0$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\text{ } \frac{n}{(n+n)^2}=0$$

Therefore:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\text{ } \frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\dots+\frac{1}{(n+n)^2}=0$$

Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have $n \to \infty$ not $x \to \infty$.

You can afford to be sloppier with the lower bound ($0$ will work), and your upper bound will be much easier to verify if you use $\dfrac{n+1}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

what you have is:
$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{(n+k)^2}$$
and if we make the substitution $u=n+k$
we can obtain:
$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{u=n}^{2n}\frac{1}{u}^2$$
which we can rewrite as:
$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\sum_{u=0}^{2n}\frac{1}{u^2}-\sum_{u=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{u^2}\right]$$
and when $n\to\infty$ these two summations are equal, so it is equal to $0$